# Download \mathcal .ttf font file

Tags: fonts, mathcal

Because I make my images for Latex in Illustrator I would like to have access to the \mathcal .ttf (or .otf). Can I find it somewhere?

I did find [this one](http://www.math.union.edu/~dpvc/jsMath/download/extra-fonts/cmbsy10/10/jsMath-cmbsy10.ttf) (cmbsy10 from [here](http://www.math.union.edu/~dpvc/jsMath/download/extra-fonts/welcome.html)), however it seems to come only in bold.

Comment: I get a lot of hits when searching for `cmsy10.ttf`. Beside this you could check latinmodern-math.otf but its script chars look a bit different.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may use jsMath font, get it from here:
https://github.com/google/fonts/blob/master/apache/jsmathcmsy10/jsMath-cmsy10.ttf

Comment: It's the same as I describe in my question, but it is by far the best one I have been able to come across, so marked as correct.

Answer (score 1):

The latex font family is Computer Modern (https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Fonts).

The one I use for my figures is Latin Modern Math, which you can download [here](http://www.gust.org.pl/projects/e-foundry/lm-math/download/index_html).

Comment: Not quite it sadly

Answer (score 0):

cmbsy is the bold version of cmsy.
[This](http://mirrors.ctan.org/fonts/cm/ps-type1/bakoma/ttf/cmsy10.ttf) may be what you are lok